# Running four short and seprate programs in one C file

Tags: c

I have been asked to upload my four programs which at the moment are running fine separately but I have been asked to submit my work in one C file. My concern is that they share similar variables, is it even possible to have one program run then close and then the second one without interference.

Comment: Windows or Unix?  How about a .cmd or .bat file for Windows and a shell script for Unix?  Should be able to pass the command-line arguments to the script through to each of your 4 programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they don't use *global* variables, sure:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    first(argc, argv);
    second(argc, argv);
    /* etc. */
}

int first(int argc, char * argv[]) /* formerly known as main() */
{
}

int second(int argc, char * argv[]) /* likewise */
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would use structs for:

```
struct {
   int intVariable;
   char *charPointer;
   double doubleVariable;
} program1_variables;
```

Then, instead of using `intVariable`, you would use `program1_variables.intVariable`.